# Show only 1 Child node of Treemap HighCharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am working on TreeMap highcharts API.

When I click on any node, then It goes to child node, but when I reach the last node, then only children are showing which have no further nodes.

My requirements are, when I click on any of that child node, then only that child node will be shown in treeMap, other child nodes should be invisible.

Below is my code.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    series: [{
        type: 'treemap',
        layoutAlgorithm: 'squarified',
        allowDrillToNode: true,
        animationLimit: 1000,
        allowTraversingTree: true,
        interactByLeaf : false,
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: false
        },
        levelIsConstant: false,
        levels: [{
            level: 1,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true
            },
            borderWidth: 3
        }],
        data: points
    }],
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Click points to drill down. Source: <a href="http://apps.who.int/gho/data/node.main.12?lang=en">WHO</a>.'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Global Mortality Rate 2012, per 100 000 population'
    },  
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            events: {
                click: function (event) {
                    if (event.point.node.childrenTotal == 0) {
                       alert('test')                           
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Please help me out on this line

```
if (event.point.node.childrenTotal == 0){
    //
 }
```

What we need to write in this line to show only the clickable node in a treemap, other nodes should be invisible.

Or, is there any other property which handles this requirement without the click event.

Comment: Could you reproduce your case on some online editor with sample data? Without the data, I am not sure how your chart looks like and how this functionality should work.

Comment: @SebastianWędzel here is a demo link

https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/treemap-large-dataset/
What I want to achieve, below are the steps
• Click on South-East Asia 
• Then click on India
• Then click on Non-communicable diseases
• Then I need to show only Non-communicable diseases node in full-screen (because It has no further child node)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this effect you need to define your data in a proper way - nested a next child to the point which is in the middle in the hierarchy. Like here:

```
  series: [{
    type: "treemap",
    allowDrillToNode: true,
    data: [{
        id: 'B',
        name: 'Bananas',
        color: "#ECE100"
      }, {
        name: 'Test',
        parent: 'B',
        id: 'Test',
        value: 10
      }, {
        name: 'Test',
        parent: 'Test',
        value: 2
      }]
  }]
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Lkzpey9v/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.treemap.allowDrillToNode

Comment: Thanks, Sebastian for your reply. I have an idea now and it is very useful.